# Remove ms-core-header ms-tablerow

Tags: master-page, custom-masterpage, design, oslo

How do I remove this from SharePoint without messing up the page?

I am using the Oslo MasterPage.

```
<div id="titlerow" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-core-header ms-tableRow">
```

On my site if I delete this element with the IE Developer Tools, the page looks like this (which is what I want):

[image]

However when I delete this line from the master page it looks like this?

[image]

Any ideas what I can do to get it to work the way I want it?

Comment: are those ootb master page and css? are you removing the closing div properly? perhaps you may want to try and leave the div there, just add display:none or visibility:hidden instead. sometimes sharepoint makes crazy calculations on existing div elements

Comment: Yes this is the ootb oslo master page. Where do I insert the display:none or visibility:hidden?

Comment: <div id="titlerow" style="display:none" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-core-header ms-tableRow">

Comment: excellent, just what the doctor ordered! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can "remove" that element with an inline style.

e.g.

```
<div id="titlerow" style="display:none" class="ms-dialogHidden ms-core-header ms-tableRow">
```

or css,

```
#titlerow{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove margins from **siteIcon** ID, it will reduce the header height of SharePoint Site.

```
#siteIcon
{
    margin:0px 20px !important;
}
```